# intellij on linux: Not picking up dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just installed intellij idea in my home directory of a research cluster (Centos)

- When I compile and run from the terminal using mvn install, all works fine.
- When I check the settings for maven on intellij, the repository setting is correct.
- I have tried reimporting the dependencies.

And yet, every time I look at code, all the dependenices are marked as not found

Any ideas as to what is going worng?

[image]

Comment: Could you please create issue on YouTrack attaching sample project: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL ?

Comment: How about performing a 'Invalidate Caches / Restart...'?